# How to make particles not disappeared after frame end?

Tags: particles, add-on

I baked the particles by using molecular add-on.

The simulation ends at frame 50, and I cannot see the particle at frame 51

Frame 50
[image]

Frame 51
[image]

It is obvious that the particle disappears after the simulation ends.

I want the particle at frame 50 does not disappear, even I cannot manipulate it.

Is there anyone knows how to do that?

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Molecular addon, so I'm not sure if I'm thinking in the right direction... but I cannot see the particles' lifetime settings. Does only the simulation end at frame 50 or the life of the particles, too? If so, did you check _Particle Properties_ > _Render_ > _Extra_ > _Dead_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon mentioned:

Change your lifetime to a bigger frame/value like e.g. 100

your settings:

[image]

result, if you changed the lifetime to 100:

[image]

or, if you just wanna "see" them, but they shouldn't be simulated, just check "dead" here:

[image]